# Can't display List of Objects

Tags: c#, list, collections, foreach, console

I have a list of objects that contains several lists with strings. When I display a list of objects using foreach cycle, everything appears as it should, but when I try to display the two objects out of the loop in the console I see only the first object. I will be grateful for helping

```
        items = new List<Object>();
        items = fileOp.GetAnylisedCollection(PATH);

        foreach (Object lists in items)
        {
            foreach (String list in (List<String>)lists)
            {
                Console.Write(list + " | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        List<string> check = (List<string>)items[0];
        Console.WriteLine(check[0] + check[1]);
```

Function which return List:

```
public List<Object> GetAnylisedCollection(String path)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int prevSeparate = 0;
        string line;
        string toList = String.Empty;
        List<Object> items = new List<Object>();
        List<string> item = new List<string>();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

        //reading file line by line to string array
        string[] str = new string[200];

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            str[count] = line;
            count++;
        }
        Array.Resize(ref str, count);

        //array analysis and writing to collection
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            char[] temp = str[i].ToCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
            {
                toList = string.Empty;
                if (temp[j].Equals('|'))
                {
                    if (prevSeparate != 1) prevSeparate++;

                    for (int k = prevSeparate; k < j; k++)
                    {
                        toList += temp[k].ToString();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(toList);
                    item.Add(toList);
                    prevSeparate = j;
                }
            }
            items.Add(item);
            item = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Console output:

```
//output using foreach


 | Boston Logan International (BOS) | New York John F Kennedy (JFK) | 1200 | 10.11.2013 | 
 | Boston Logan International (BOS) | Sacramento International (SMF) | 430 | 10.11.2013 | 
 | Cleveland Hopkins International (CLE) | Sacramento International (SMF) | 543 |1.11.2013| 
 | Beijing Capital (PEK) | New York John F Kennedy (JFK) | 2500 | 13.11.2013 | 
 | Moscow Domodedovo (DME) | Boston Logan International (BOS) | 1230 | 15.11.2013 | 
 | Washington Ronald Reagan (DCA) | Durango La Plata (DRO) | 340 | 14.11.2013 | 
 | Atlanta Hartsfield-Jackson ATL (ATL) | Washington Ronald Reagan (DCA) | 450 | 7.11.2013| 
 | Sacramento International (SMF) | Atlanta Hartsfield-Jackson ATL (ATL) | 325 | 6.11.2013|
 | New York John F Kennedy (JFK) | Beijing Capital (PEK) | 2300 | 19.11.2013 | 
 | Cleveland Hopkins International (CLE) | New York John F Kennedy (JFK) | 360 | 2.11.2013| 


//simple output


Boston Logan International (BOS)
```

This was to be displayed as:

> Boston Logan International (BOS) New York John F Kennedy (JFK)

Comment: Maybe your 2nd item is null or empty? Impossible to say without more information. You could try writing each string on a separate line to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Why are you calling a single string `list`?

Comment: Another question, what should have been displayed? How shall the correct display look alike for you?

Comment: From the list of objects I get an object and convert it into a List of strings. I want to print on the first and second elements are contained in first List. List is not empty as a cycle foreach of these items are displayed

Comment: This was to be displayed as: Boston Logan International (BOS) New York John F Kennedy (JFK)

Comment: Why are you creating a new `List<Object>` in the first line of your sample, only to throw that object away in the 2nd line?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It makes sense to do what the OP did. Kind of it does make for a specific case. GetAnylisedCollection might throw error in such case list will stay assigned and foreach wont scream error message. Foreach doesnt like null. :)

Comment: @devhedgehog if an exception is thrown, there's no handler. The code will stop

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Maybe the OP has a try with an empty catch in that method... Maybe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is not how you suppose. Look at the first char on your lines. It is a pipe, but this char should never be printed at the start of your line, but only after the first item extracted from the first list.
Your first line should be (the same for the next lines)

```
Boston Logan International (BOS) | New York John F Kennedy (JFK) | 1200 | 10.11.2013 |
```

without the pipe character.
So perhaps your first list of list contains a first element that contains an empty space

you could try this code to prove this

```
List<string> check = (List<string>)items[0];
if(check.Count > 2)
    Console.WriteLine(check[1] + check[2]);
```

Comment: I understand what needs to be displayed so, but it appears as I have shown, and I did not even guess what the problem is. I tried to insert the code, but the output is the same

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the  init of the internal loop. When your code reach the breakpoint you could easily continue with a step by step and check the values contained in the first item of the first list

Comment: Thank you so much. It turned out that the first element of the items List was empty because it had all the problems. Debugger cool thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
| Boston Logan International (BOS) | New York John F Kennedy (JFK) | 1200 | 10.11.2013 |
```

And now take a look at this code:

```
foreach (String list in (List<String>)lists)
{
    Console.Write(list + " | ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

The first string is empty and therefore you have the or sign displayed.